# How to get prototxt in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm using it for **Face mask detection testing for images.**

```
!pip install ProtoText
Collecting ProtoText
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/50/306035a7314df99686177e16e4f197bf310b1bcabdce7f7d8671342ca4b0/ProtoText-0.3.5.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

The ProtoText module you are using is associated with https://github.com/XericZephyr/prototext.

It is not mentioned clearly, but I found that this module works for python2.
By default Google colaboratory provides python3, python2 is deprecated from google colaboratory.
Though you can use python2 in google colaboratory using this link

https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=python2

You can use `!python --version` to check the version then use `!pip install ProtoText`.

It should work